# Proving second order stationarity of stochastic process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Given the stochastic process $X_t=A\sin t+B\cos t,t\in\Bbb R$, where $A,B$ are independent random variables with zero expectation and equal variance $\sigma^2$. I am required to show that $\{X_t\}$ is a stationary stochastic process of second order.

I have shown that it is weakly stationary by showing that the expectation of $X_t$ is constant (zero) and $E[X_{t_1}\cdot X_{t_2}]=\sigma^2\cos(t_1-t_2)=f(|t_1-t_2|)$. But I suspect I have to show that the joint distribution of $X_{t_1},X_{t_2}$ is the same as that of $X_{t_1+h},X_{t_2+h}$ for $h>0$ but without knowing the distribution of $A,B$, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $Law(A) \neq Law(B)$, $\{ X_t \}$ will not be a stationary process of first order. Because $X_0 = B$ and $X_{\pi/2} =A$ and therefore you will find $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$ P(X_0 \le x) = P(B \le x) \neq P(A\le x) = P(X_{\pi/2}\le x). $$

Even when $A$ and $B$ are iid with mean 0, first order stationarity will not hold. Take for example $A,B \sim U [-1, 1]$ independent. Then again $X_0 = B$ and $X_{\pi/4} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(A+B)$ do not have the same distributions as $P(B > 1) =0$ by definition but $P(A+B > \sqrt{2}) > 0$.

Comment: I think you wanted to say when $A,B$ are not identically distributed. Say I know $A,B$ are identically distributed, but not the actual distributions. Is this information sufficient for second order stationarity?

Comment: You are right. I edited the answer.

Comment: When $A,B$ are iid normal, stationarity of second order holds. So I take that without knowing the distribution of $A,B$ it is not possible to show what the question asks. May I suggest you add this to your answer? I will accept it.